# MongoDB Error: 16 Invalid Length when sharding a large collection

Tags: mongodb

When sharding a large collection, I receive the following error message.
Mongodb version 3.6
chunk sizes tried: 64, 128, 512, 1024
There is no more information than this in the error.  How can I find out what is causing this?

````
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "InvalidLength",
    "code" : 16,
    "codeName" : "InvalidLength",
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1624108643, 8),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1624108643, 53),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"WQ9ND4K0tw0iNbxnyoa9F9WzufM="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6948599486780276762")
        }
    }
}```

Logs:
2021-06-19T13:09:32.317+0000 I SHARDING [conn37512] request split points lookup for chunk test.test47 { : MinKey } -->> { : MaxKey }
2021-06-19T13:12:09.326+0000 W SHARDING [conn37512] Finding the split vector for test.test47 over { _id: "hashed" } keyCount: 60 numSplits: 2235327 lookedAt: 53 took 157009ms
````